# what is the value $A\cap B?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sphere $(S^2)$

Take open set $A=S^2\setminus \{n\} $ and $B=S^2\setminus\{s\} $ where  $n$ and  $s$  denote  the north  and  south poles  respectively

Now  my question is that   what is the value $A\cap B?$

My attempt :$S^2\setminus \{n\} \cap S^2\setminus\{s\}=A\cap B=\text{equator of sphere} $. See the diagram  below.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Kas.png)

Comment: It is worth noting that this result ($A \cap B = S^2\backslash \{n,s\}$) has nothing to do with spheres. So it would be useful to know the context where it came up. E.g. smooth structure on $S^2$ with the sets you named and their corresponding stereographic projections. And perhaps you are interested in verifying the transition maps are smoothly compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A \cap B =\\
= (S^2\setminus \{n\}) \cap (S^2\setminus\{s\}) = \\
= \{x \in S^2 : x \neq n\} \cap \{x \in S^2 : x \neq s\} = \\
= \{x \in S^2 : x \neq n\ \wedge x \neq s\},$$

where $x$ is a generic point of (on) the sphere (sphere surface) $S^2$, and $\wedge$ is the logical connector "AND".

You can also rewrite the previous as follows:

$$A \cap B = S^2 \setminus \{n, s\}.$$

Comment: okay .what  is  the meaning of  $\wedge $  symbol ?

Comment: @wasiu I've updated my answer. Please, check it.

Comment: okay got  it .Thanks you @the_candyman